# TypeError: game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am actually pretty new to this, when I run my code I get error as `TypeError: game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'` and I want to keep track of the gusses entered by the user so, I have doubt in declaring the list b i.e if I declare `b` in `objects()` then I am unable to use that list in `game()`. I need some help to fix this.
Here is my code:

```
def objects():
import random
x=random.randint(1,9)
game(x)
def game(x):
b=[]
a=int(input('Enetr the number between 1 and 9'))
b.append(a)
print ('till now you have entered ')
print(b)

if a==x:
    print('Correct guess')
    b=input('Do you want to do it again if not then press exit' )
    if b=='exit':
        exit
    else:
        objects()
elif a>x:
    print('too big')
    game()
else:
    print ('too small')
    game()
```

Comment: fix your indentation as it appears on your script. Second your `game()` function takes one argument and you are calling `game()` at the end of your script.... Just make the end call `game(x)`

Comment: Instead of recursion use `while` loop and do the logic in it.

Comment: yes @MooingRawr if I do` game(x)` at the end of the script it is working correctly. And can you help me even in declaring list `b` because the list gets empty again as I call `game(x)`.

Comment: @metmirr actually I am finding it difficult if i use while loop, can you just give a little idea how to do it in this program.

Comment: @KedarKodgire If you need to keep the state of certain variables while `looping` use a `while loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined game as `def game(x):` so it needs an argument. You then call it with `game()` which has no arguments.

Also, remember that Python cares about indentation.

You probably either want to define `game` with no arguments, and set `x` inside the body and use a `while` loop, or call `game(x)` in the function call if `x` doesnt change.

Let's take the no-arguments + while loop approach

```
def run_game():
    def game():
        # set up x and b here
        guess = None # that way guess won't equal x the first time around
        while guess != x:
            guess = int(input('Enetr the number between 1 and 9'))
            b.append(guess)
            print ('till now you have entered ')
            print(b)
            # do the guessing logic
        # play again?
        # yes
            game()
    game()
```

You can make some improvements here, but thats the gist of it

Comment: why would you suggest OP to remove the argument, when it's clearly needed in what he wants to do, the way he wants to do it.

Comment: Oh I missed that line... oops

Comment: edited. My bad...

Comment: If I do `def game()` then i wont be able to use x further.

Comment: yeah I edited....

Comment: yes i got it and even i'm getting difficulty in list `b` as it is getting empty again as i call `game(x)` can you just help me a little bit with that.

Comment: Don't use recursion. Use a while loop. I'll update my answer with a sketch